# Software to automatically detect (and if it possible remove) commercials from video files recorded from TV

Tags: video-editor

I have recorded some TV shows to my PC. They have commercials. And I want to remove those commercials.
I want to know if there is a software that can automatically parse a video file or a batch of files and at least detect the points in time when commercials start and end, and remove/delete those scenes or provide that info in some standard format that can be latter used in another software to do the remotion part of the job?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Comskip (https://github.com/erikkaashoek/Comskip). I use it with TvHeadend to mark commercials, which are then auto-skipped during playback in Kodi.

There is a paid-for, pre-built version for Windows, or if you are comfortable you can build it yourself from source code.